# Genre of Moshimoss' "Slow Days It Was Super"

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

[Moshimoss - "Slow Days It Was Super"](https://youtu.be/r2qXQLYE2A0)

I heard this song and this is amazing, and it's something I've never heard before. What is the genre of this kind of music? Are there other artists who make music like this?

Comment: I would probably place it in Indie Electronic.

Comment: Ambient Electronic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"NU AGE" describes the specific genre for this song. Here you go, a list of some of the Nu Age artists who produce similar music of this genre:

Emanuele Errante Szymon Kaliski P Jørgensen Fennesz & Sakamoto A-Sun Amissa David Wenngren Danny Norbury Caught in the Wake Forever Hior Chronik Keith Kenniff Tobias Hellkvist The Toy Library From the Mouth of the Sun Stormloop Carousell Illuha Clem Leek Paul Jebanasam SaffronKeira Christopher Tignor Marsen Jules Trio Gimu Spheruleus Isnaj Dui Black Swan Konntinent Richard Skelton Loren Dent Nickolas Mohanna Chubby Wolf Markus Mehr Marta Mist Gurun Gurun Bersarin Quartett Julien Neto Willamette Part Timer Jannick Schou Offthesky Concert Silence Murralin Lane Gultskra Artikler Mico Nonet Corey Fuller Olan Mill Strom Noir Lüüp Kinder Scout Rudi Arapahoe Hybernation Peter Prautzsch Goldmund Philippe Petit Saito Koji The OO-Ray I've Lost Marcus Fischer Bengalfuel Elintseeker Moon Ate the Dark Antonymes Joe Frawley Worrytrain Martin Herterich David Newlyn Yann Novak Gareth Dickson Talvihorros Daniel W J Mackenzie Sublamp Damian Valles Listening Mirror Hallock Hill Zazie Von Einem Anderen Stern Frédéric D. Oberland Taishi Kamiya Nicolas Bernier Matteo Sommacal Radere Herion Pjusk Keith Freund Deryck Sterne Two People In A Room Robert Curgenven Causeyoufair Anna Rose Carter Ryan Teague Josh Varnedore The Boats Hakobune A Winged Victory for the Sullen Danny Saul Le Lendemain Christopher Hipgrave Hessien June 1974 The Green Kingdom Ex Confusion Attilio Novellino Ekca Liena Hior Chronik Celer Birds of Passage Marsen Jules Nobuto Suda Marcus Fjellström Kane Ikin Sun Hammer Tomasz Bednarczyk Pinkcourtesyphone Qluster Ian Hawgood Good Night & Good Morning Northerner Widesky Aquarelle Guy Gelem Solo Andata Henning Schmiedt Tom White Petrels Logreybeam Fjordne Koen Holtka.

Comment: This is really not much of an answer. Perhaps some references to pages describing the genre as well as links to the band pages?

Comment: Is this a term people use? It sounds plausible, but I couldn't find any citations for it online.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best described as ["Ambient Electronica"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOm9Jy3EFWY) or [chillout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chill-out_music).  The features are low-key, trancelike, atmospheric beats using electronic instruments (or sometimes a blend of electronic and acoustic).